# NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/InvalidationListener

Tags: java, jar, javafx, classpath

The following error appears when running a program.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/InvalidationListener
```

The command line follows

```
java -cp "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jfxrt.jar" -jar MyProgram.jar
```

Jar exists:

```
>dir "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\*.jar"
 Volume in drive C is SYS
 Volume Serial Number is 2CD4-0B40

 Directory of C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib

04.10.2013  01:32           172 765 alt-rt.jar
04.10.2013  01:32         3 605 930 charsets.jar
04.10.2013  01:32         4 374 572 deploy.jar
04.10.2013  01:32           890 363 javaws.jar
04.10.2013  01:32           109 196 jce.jar
04.10.2013  01:32           532 559 jfr.jar
04.10.2013  01:32        15 106 233 jfxrt.jar
04.10.2013  01:32           581 198 jsse.jar
04.10.2013  01:32               385 management-agent.jar
04.10.2013  01:32         1 921 341 plugin.jar
04.10.2013  01:32         2 448 362 resources.jar
04.10.2013  01:32        59 966 803 rt.jar
              12 File(s)     89 709 707 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  43 361 476 608 bytes free
```

File inside it exists

```
>jar tf "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jfxrt.jar" | D:\APPS\cygwin\bin\grep InvalidationListener
com/sun/javafx/fxml/BeanAdapter$PropertyInvalidationListener.class
javafx/beans/InvalidationListener.class
javafx/beans/WeakInvalidationListener.class
javafx/scene/media/MediaView$MediaErrorInvalidationListener.class
```

What it wants?

Comment: Please show your code in which you are getting the error.

Comment: Do you have any META-INF inside jar file?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> **-jar**
>         When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

When you supply both `-jar` and `-cp` arguments, the custom classpath you supply is completely ignored.

For Java 7, JavaFX is not on the default classpath.  For a standalone JavaFX application jar to work on Java 7, you must package the jar using the [JavaFX deployment tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) or 3rd party [maven](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) or [gradle](https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle) plugins.  Such packaging tools insert JavaFX lookup code into the packaged jar to find an appropriate JavaFX version on the system.

Everything is lot simpler if you just use [Oracle Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) rather than using Java 7.  Wth Oracle Java 8, Java is on the default classpath, so when you run your JavaFX application jar using `java -jar`, it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError:Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine tries to load in the definition of a class and no definition of the class could be found.